# Проблема с доступом к данным класса с++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, visual-c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:

    int** arr;
    int rows, cols;

public:
    
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int a, int b);
    Matrix(const Matrix& copy);
    Matrix operator+ (Matrix& a);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Matrix& a);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Matrix& a);
    ~Matrix();
};

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    arr = nullptr;
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int a, int b)
{
    arr = new int* [rows = a];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[cols = b];
    }
 }

 Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& copy)
 {
     this->rows = copy.rows;
     this->cols = copy.cols;
     this->arr = new int* [copy.rows];
         for (int i = 0; i < copy.rows; i++)
         {
            this->arr[i] = new int[copy.cols];
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < copy.rows; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < copy.cols; j++)
             {
                 this->arr[i][j] = copy.arr[i][j];
             }
         }
 }

 Matrix::~Matrix()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
         if (arr[i] != nullptr)
         {
             delete[] arr[i];
         }
     }
     if (arr != nullptr)
     {
         delete[] arr;
         arr = nullptr;
     }
  } 

  istream& operator>> (istream& in, Matrix& a)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++)
          {
               in >> a.arr[i][j];
          }
      }
      return in;
  }

  ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Matrix& a)
  {

for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++)
    {
        out << a.arr[i][j] << '\t';
    }
    out << endl;
}
out << endl;
return out;
}

 Matrix Matrix::operator+ (Matrix& a)
 {
     Matrix res(a.rows, a.cols);
     for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++)
        {
            res.arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] + a.arr[i][j];
        }
     }
     return res;
 }

 int main()
 {
     Matrix a1(2,2);
     Matrix a2(2,2);
     cin >> a1;
     cin >> a2;
    cout << a1;
     cout << a2;
     Matrix d;
     d = a1 + a2;
     cout << d;
     return 0;
  }
```

Проблема такая, при компиляции падает программа и выдает ошибку(Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00F329A1 в 1(2).exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу) указывая в место прегрузки оператора вывода, в отладчике написано, что чтение a.arr невозможно, хотя другие прегрузки с аналогичным кодом функционируют нормально. Также ошибка появляется только после перегрузки оператора сложения. Если его убрать, то ввод и вывод матриц работают отлично.
Как быть и что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет оператора присваивания, в результате вот тут

```
Matrix d;
d = a1 + a2;
```

используется генерируемый компилятором (с поверхностным копированием), и вы получаете проблемы.

Кстати, в варианте

```
Matrix d = a1 + a2;
```

[все бы работало](https://ideone.com/oPq8Nt), потому что тут работал бы конструктор копирования.

Рекомендую дописать оператор присваивания через конструктор копирования и функцию обмена, так:

```
    Matrix& operator = (Matrix copy) { swap(copy); return *this; }

private:
    void swap(Matrix& m)
    {
        int ** ta = arr; arr = m.arr; m.arr = ta;
        int t = rows; rows = m.rows; m.rows = t;
        t = cols; cols = m.cols; m.cols = t;
    }
```

И все будет нормально: https://ideone.com/UKL4eL